# Need a powershell script to update 300+ SharePoint SitePages

Tags: pnp-powershell, powershell-script, sharepoint-online-powershell

Is there a PowerShell/PNP script that will update all "Highlighted Content" web parts within multiple site pages within a site? Need to update the web part Layout from "Grid" view to "List" view and don't want to have to do each manually??

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: one sec - i have an old script from my on-prem days that might work for this.  I'm currently testing it...

Comment: @Taco_Buffet appreciate you looking into it. Any luck?

Comment: close, it looked as simple as updating one property, but there's a little more to it.

Comment: Here's where I'm at:   the two properties that need to be updated are layoutId and templateId.   I'm struggling to get the JSON correct.  The values should be something like:    "layoutId" = '"list"'   and   "templateId" = 2

Comment: @Taco_Buffet Yeah thats where i am stuck at too. This is the script that runs fine but when refreshing the page, the webpart that i am testing comes back with and error saying "there is something that went wrong"

Comment: `$page= Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "TEST.aspx"`
`$webpart = $page.Controls  | ? {$_.InstanceId -eq "<InstanceID>"}`
`$WebpartJson = $webpart.PropertiesJson `
`$webpartobj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $webpartJson `
`IF($webpartobj.layoutId -eq "Card") {
       
   $webpartobj.layoutId = "List"
   $webpartobj.templateId = 2
   
   }`
`$webpartJson = $webpartobj | ConvertTo-Json -Compress`
`$webpart.PropertiesJson = $webpartJson `
`Set-PnPPage -Identity $page -Publish `

Comment: did that work?.

Comment: @Taco_Buffet No I just get that "Something went wrong" error when refreshing the page/webpart. Which states, ERROR:
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')"

Comment: I'm waiting for my security team to approve my request to upgrade my PowerShell install to: Register-PnPManagementShellAccess .  After that, I'll take another stab at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Taco_Buffet

Got it figured out! Here's what I used to gather all highlighted content WebParts for all site pages for a specific site. Was able to change layoutID from "Card" ("Grid" view in UI) along with also updating the max items to 500.

```
$Site= Get-SPOSite -Identity <SiteURL>
$pages= Get-PnPListItem -List sitepages
Foreach($page in $pages) {
    WRITE-HOST Checking $Page.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"]
    $pageName= $page.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"]
    $pg= Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity $pageName
    $WebParts= $pg.Controls
     Foreach($WebPart in $WebParts | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "Highlighted Content"}) {
         Write-Host Getting WebPart Instance ID
          $WPInstID= $WebPart.InstanceId 
          $WpPJ= $Webpart.PropertiesJson
     WRITE-HOST Converting from JSON
     $WpJ= ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WpPJ
       WRITE-HOST Changing $WPInstID to LIST VIEW
            IF($WpJ.layoutId -eq "Card") {
              $WpJ.layoutId = "List"
              $WpJ.templateId = 2
              $WpJ.maxItemsPerPage = 500}
      Set-PnPPageWebPart -Page $PageName -Identity $WPInstID -PropertiesJson (ConvertTo-JSON  $WpJ -Compress -Depth 10)
    }
   }
```

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out!  I'm stilllll waiting for my team to authorize access to the updated pnp.powershell module.